# How to design a system for Search query and Csv/Pdf export for 500GB data/day?

Tags: elasticsearch

**Problem Stmt**

1 device is sending 500GB text data (logs) per day to my central server.
I want to design a system using which user can:

1. Apply exact-match filters and go through data using pagination
2. Export PDF/CSV reports for same query as above

Data can be stored for max 6 months. Its an on-premise solution. Some delay on queries is affordable. If we can do data compressions it would be awesome. I have 512GB RAM, 80core system and TBs of storage(these are upgradable)

**What I have tried/found out:**

Tech stack iam planning to use: MEAN stack for application dev. For core data part iam planning to use ELK stack. Elasticsearch single index can have <40-50gb ideal size recommendation.
So, my plan is create 100 indexes per day each of 5GB for each device. During query I can sort these indices based on their name (eg. 12_dec_2012_part_1 ...) and search into each index linearly and keep on doing this till the range user has asked. (I think this will hold good for ad-hoc request by user, but for reports if I do this and write to a csv file by going sequentially one by one it will take long time.) For reports I think best thing i can do is create pdf/csv for each index(5gb size), reason because most file openers cannot open very large csv/pdf files.

*Iam new to big data problems. Iam not sure what approach is right; ELK or Hadoop ecosystem for this. (I would like to go with ELK)*

**Can someone point me to right direction or how to proceed or if someone has dealt with this type of problem statement? Any out of the way solution for these problems are also welcome.
Thanks!**

Comment: I have a question regarding the MEAN stack? Why you need an application for handling this? You can use ELK with hourly based indexes, so that you are not worried with the data or retrieval. I am currently handling handling 4M records/15min, with very smaller configuration. You can easily achieve with your current server conf.

Comment: MEAN stack is there to have a UI and backend to serve client. I cannot show kibana to my client. Node server will query elasticsearch and return results to angular. what is your config Jinna what do you suggest. Are you using single node or multiple? thnkz

Comment: If you have multiple VMS Multi-Node cluster is the best practice. But disaster recovery is something you need to takecare of if the underlying hardware failures.  Very basic container for running single node https://jinnabalu.com/Elasticsearch-Single-Node-using-Docker-Compose/

You can also use low code or no code like appsmith options rather MEAN. MEAN is not a cost effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

- **exact-match filters**

You can use `term` query or `match_phrase` query

> Returns documents that contain an exact term in a provided field.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

- **pagination**

You can use `from` and `size` parameter to pagination.

```
GET /_search
{
  "from": 5,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "user.id": "kimchy"
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html

- **Export PDF/CSV**
  You can use Kibana

> Kibana provides you with several options to share Discover saved
> searches, dashboards, Visualize Library visualizations, and Canvas
> workpads.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/reporting-getting-started.html

- **Data can be stored for max 6 months**
  You can use ILM policy

> You can configure index lifecycle management (ILM) policies to
> automatically manage indices according to your performance,
> resiliency, and retention requirements. For example, you could use ILM
> to:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html

- **optimal shard size**
  For log indices you can use datastream indices.

> A data stream lets you store append-only time series data across
> multiple indices while giving you a single named resource for
> requests. Data streams are well-suited for logs, events, metrics, and
> other continuously generated data.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/data-streams.html

> When you use datastream indices you don't think about shard size it
> will rollover automatically. :)

- **For the compression you should update index settings**

  index.codec: best_compression

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html

Comment: thnx musab for detailed ans, actually i already have idea about how to implement these features using elk, iam concerned about the large data size and to whether this approach is right or not

Comment: In best practices it's recommended to keep shard size between 10-50GB, if this satisfied your scenario looks good.

Comment: Also you need to consider that a node can have max 1k shards in default, you can change this but it can cause out-of-memory and slowness if you have a lot of shards

Comment: Also it's recommended to keep a node RAM 60GB and heap size 30GB

Comment: Also it's recommended to have dedicated master nodes, data nodes, and coordinator nodes,
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/high-availability-cluster-design.html

Comment: If you decide to use the ELK stack, I highly recommend hiring an Elasticsearch engineer or freelancer. A poorly designed Elasticsearch cluster, index mapping/template would be a complete disappointment.